# Deleting a local branch named like 'origin/branchName'

Tags: git

I installed git on my server and in an effort to pull the master branch, I did: `git checkout origin/branchname` which resulted in a branch on my server repo called "origin/branchname". Afterward, I learned the right way to get the branch (using fetch and pull) but I still have origin/branchname in my server repo. I have two questions:

1. What is that? How is it different than the "normal" branchname that I created using pull?
2. Is it safe to delete origin/branchname on my server repo? Is there any risk to the central repository? I doubt this would be the case, but I wanted to check before doing it.

**Clarification:** I don't want to change anything in my central repository (we use bitbucket). I just want to delete the origin/branchname on one of my distributions with disrupting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`origin/branchName` is a valid name for a local branch. If you run `git branch` and you see it listed there, it means it is a local branch and it can be safely removed (without messing with any remote branch) with:

```
git branch -d origin/branchName
```

If you have a branch named like this, and you also happen to have a remote branch that would resolve to the same name, when you run git commands using this reference you will receive warnings:

```
git show origin/branchName
warning: refname 'origin/branchName' is ambiguous.
```

Answer (score 1):

`<remote name>/<branch name>` indicates last known state of branch `<branch name>` on remote repository `<remote name>`. It moves its position every time you fetch something new from remote repository for branch `<branch name>`. It is not a branch it is more like dynamic tag showing state of remote repository.
It is useful so do not delete it.

Comment: Aha. That explains why when I do `git status` on branchname it tells me where I am in relation to origin/branchname. I could see why I might want to keep it, but can we first establish whether there is any risk in deleting it? Would it have any impact on the origin branchname?

Answer (score 0):

If you see it as a "Unique" Branch and you can see your "new" branch too.  I would say, it is ok to delete it "`git push :[branch_to_delete]`"

You can delete it locally this way : `git branch -d [branch_to_delete]` and the branch will still be available in the "cloud"

Comment: Thanks. Please check my update above. I think my questions was unclear .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can safely delete the branch.

If you have Git v1.7.0 installed, you can delete a remote branch using :

git push origin --delete 'branchName'

which has a more intuitive syntax than :

git push origin :'branchName'

Comment: Thanks. Please check my update above. I think my questions was unclear .

Comment: Careful, this will delete the branch in the remote.